# Can't chose a Liferay Plugin SDK in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, sdk, liferay

I have checked out an existing project from SVN into Eclipse as aLiferay project (in fact the checked in project IS a Liferay project). 
The problem is that I get an error:

> ```
>        *No Liferay Plugin SDK configured on project Xxx-portlet.*
> ```
>
> Opening the project properties I can see under Liferay menue item that indeed there is no SDK selected. Following the *Configure SDKs* link I can see an existing installed Liferay Plugin SDK and it's already selected. Clicking *OK* (even after de- and re-selecting the installed Plugin SDK) the input field remains empty. 
>   How can I assign the Liferay Plugin SDK to the project??

Comment: What version of Liferay do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugins SDK is an ant-based download that relies on your projects to be in common locations: If you just check out one project, you'll need to have this in a subdirectory of the plugins sdk - e.g. if you are working on a portlet (project name "my-portlet"), this should be located in `${plugins-sdk}/portlets/my-portlet`.

In eclipse (or Liferay IDE) you should configure your plugins sdk by naming it and pointing to the root of your sdk folders. Then you can choose to create projects into this sdk (or to import from that SDK)

Note that the sourcecode will be located in the SDK directory, not in the eclipse workspace directory.

This is necessary as IDE relies on the ANT infrastructure to be there and the build.xml files reference common build.xml files in the parent directory. Some build processes in Liferay IDE will trigger ANT.

Liferay IDE 2.0 will also support maven, so this requirement will go away (if you use maven)

Answer (score -1):

Ok! I have to check out the project into the {Liferay Plugin SDK}/portlets folder but not into any other folder.

Comment: you should rather add this statement as a comment (e.g. to my answer, I beliveve it's directed to it), not as yet another answer